# how to connect two schemas one in local host and one in remote computer

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, glassfish-3

How to connect two mysql schemas one in localhost and other in computer in hibernate in j2ee project using glassfish server. I have created 2 persistence units and 2 data sources. Is it the correct way to do this? 
Data retrieving can be done from both schemas.
 But it throws

> java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection.Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Local transaction already has 1 non-XA Resource: cannot add more resources. "  exception when updating the database.

Have you any ideas to do this?

Comment: Did you use two session factories or not

Comment: Pls post your configuration and code for helpful answer.

Comment: There is no session factory created that created by me.

Comment: Please add your `persistence.xml` to the question.

Comment: My answer to this questio may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950835/connecting-two-mysql-data-source-using-a-single-connection-object